# Using Net::SSH::Perl to login to remote machine

Tags: perl, ssh

I want to do ssh to remote machine using Net::SSH::Perl module.I can remotely login to the machine from command line using ssh command but not from the perl script.Can anyone help me with this

My code is:

```
 $user = 'smetest';$pass = 'smetest';
 print "user is ".$user." password is ".$pass."\n";
 print "Connecting to the Relay host " . $relayteaddress . ".\n";
 $sshrelay = Net::SSH::Perl->new($relayteaddress,  protocol => '2,1', debug => 1);
 print "logging in to Relay $relayteaddress ...\n";
 $sshrelay->login($user, $pass) || die "ssh login didn't work\n";
 print "logged into relay\n";
```

Output and debug messages:

```
user is smetest password is smetest
Connecting to the Relay host 192.168.2.175.
W10: Reading configuration data /home/systest/.ssh/config
W10: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
W10: Connecting to 192.168.2.175, port 22.
W10: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.4
W10: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 2.0.
.10: No compat match: OpenSSH_6.4
W10: Connection established.
logging in to Relay 192.168.2.175 ...
W10: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
W10: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
W10: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
W10: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
W10: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
Key class 'Net::SSH::Perl::Key::RSA' is unsupported: Cannot find current script 'CONDOR_PERF_BAND_ISM2450_80211BGN_CHANNEL_11_ACTIVE_UDP_TX_LGI_AP20' at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 205
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/FindBin.pm line 205, <GEN26> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Crypt/RSA.pm line 13, <GEN26> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Crypt/RSA.pm line 13, <GEN26> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Net/SSH/Perl/Key/RSA.pm line 14, <GEN26> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Net/SSH/Perl/Key/RSA.pm line 14, <GEN26> line 1.
Compilation failed in require at (eval 45) line 1, <GEN26> line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 45) line 1, <GEN26> line 1.
```

Comment: FindBin is used to locate the script that's executing (in order to find related files in nearby directories). It can fail if `chdir` is used.

Comment: Am not using chdir,i don't know why it says it can't find that file

Comment: Is your script actually named `CONDOR_PERF_BAND_ISM2450_80211BGN_CHANNEL_11_ACTIVE_UDP_TX_LGI_AP20`?

Comment: No actually script name is throughput.pm but it is called by a diff script named 'throughput.pl',but CONDOR_PERF_BAND_ISM2450_80211BGN_CHANNEL_11_ACTIVE_UDP_TX_LGI_AP20 is label name of script which is created by throughput.pl file

Comment: No idea what it means for a script "to create a label name". Changing `$0` would also prevent FindBin from finding the script. Is that what you mean you did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently having issues getting ssh to work using Net::SSH::Perl but I created this script as simple work around for the moment. Hope it helps anyone in a similar situation.  Obviously the commands are more or less just demo of issuing multiple commands once connected.

```
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Expect;

  $exp= Expect->spawn("ssh $host -l $user");

  $exp->expect($timeout,"Password:");
  $exp->send("$pass\r");

  $exp->expect($timeout,-re,'>');
  $exp->send("ls -l\r");

  $exp->expect($timeout,-re,'>');
  $exp->send("mkdir aDir\r");

  $exp->expect($timeout,-re,'>');
  $exp->send("chmod 777 aDir\r");

  $exp->expect($timeout,-re,'>');
  $exp->send("exit\r");
```